# GWT - Consolidate error messages to use them across server and client

Tags: hibernate, gwt, error-handling, resourcebundle

I am working on a GWT project. I provide error messages at two places right now - Hibernate Validator annotations and in setter validations. These messages are identical. Also, they are likely to be identical on UI side, too.

Instead of writing the same strings at three different places, I would like to consolidate them in a single resource, and make the resource accessible to the project.

I have thought of using a properties file in the "shared" package, which then could be accessed using ResourceBundle.
However, it means that I will have to instantiate the bundle in the entity classes, which I don't find good. The entity classes become essentially dependent on the bundles.
However, I can't find any other way, too.

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a pure abstract class to "hide" the fact that I use a ResourceBundle. Something like :

```
public abstract class MyAppMessages {

    private static ResourceBundle messagesBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("messages", Locale.FRANCE);

    private MyAppMessages() {
        // hide the utility class constructor
    }

    public static String getMessage(String key) {
        return messagesBundle.getString(key);
    }
}
```

Of course, it doesn't remove the dependance between your entity classes and your bundle access but at least you use a singleton design pattern for your static resources and only one class remains dependant over ResourceBundle. If one day you wish to use something else than ResourceBundle, you'll have to refactor only 1 class.